# oracle sql insufficient privilieges in procedure but not in worksheet

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two schemas in oracle DB, say A and B.
Schema A has a table `tabA` and Schema B as a table `tabB`.

Now in Schema B, this works:

```
select * from A.tabA
```

But, I created a package in schema B that has a procedure `FOO`. The procedure essentially does the same thing..i.e.

```
PROCEDURE FOO IS
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO B.tabB (select * from A.tabA)
END FOO
```

This doesn't compile and gives `ORA-01031 Insufficient privileges error`.
I had to go to schema A and explicitly grant `SELECT` privilege to schema B to make the procedure compile successfully.

Now `A.tabA` is not the only table and new tables will be added in the future. In the procedure `FOO`, I fetch the table name dynamically. So, It could be `A.tabC` tomorrow, `A.tabD` the day after. I don't want to manually assign the privileges in every new table created in schema A.

Why privileges are specifically required in procedure while not required in worksheet?
How to assign privileges automatically to new tables?

Answer (score 2):

A definer's rights stored procedure can't access permissions granted to a role only those granted directly to the owner. I would guess that B has been given select access on `a.tabA` via a role, which would work if you ran an ad-hoc SQL statement (assuming the role was enabled for the session) but not for a definer's rights stored procedure. Most likely, whatever administrative process manages to grant the select privilege to the role would need to be modified to grant the privilege directly to b instead of or in addition to the role.  Alternately, you could make the procedure an invoker's rights stored procedure (add `authid current_user` to the declaration before the `as`).  But that would require that any user that wants to execute the procedure would need to have access to `a.tabA` not just the procedure owner.

If you do want an invoker's rights stored procedure

```
PROCEDURE FOO 
  authid current_user
IS
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO B.tabB (select * from A.tabA);
END FOO;
```